# There exists a general formula for the following linear SDE

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I was reading a book about SDE and I encountered the following equation:
$$d\vec{X} = (\vec{A}(t) + \vec{B}(t)\vec{X})dt + (\vec{C}(t) + \vec{F}(t)\vec{X})d\vec{W},$$
$$\vec{X} = \vec{X}_0.$$
The book only gives the solution only to the case where $\vec{B}$ is constant and $\vec{F} = 0$, i. e.,
$$d\vec{X} = (\vec{A}(t) + \vec{B}\vec{X})dt + \vec{C}(t)d\vec{W}.$$
I am interested in finding the solution to the following problem:
$$dX_1 = dt + dW_1,$$
$$dX_2 = X_1dW_2.$$
I was wondering if anyone could tell me if there is a explicit formula  for the first equation or how to solve the problem that I propose as the book doesn't tell how to find the solution to the problem or doesn't give any example on the method of solution for a system.

Comment: Solve the first and then use that in the second - It seems pretty straight forward at first glance (due to the independence between the second equation and the first).

Comment: thank you. Didn't notice that